# ArcBall Camera Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to create an arcball camera for use in my 3D Android game (note: I am using the libGDX framework)... I am having trouble figuring out how to go about creating it. I can probably extend the current `PerspectiveCamera` class in libGDX and add some logic to handle the arcball rotations around a sphere, but I need an explanation about how it works. I am still learning OpenGL ES but I think I'm at a good point to attempt this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question and [this (stackoverflow) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14036014/304330) while looking for the same thing myself.

I haven't tried the code out myself yet, so I can't confirm whether it works or not.

I'm going to need something similar myself for my game idea, just wanted to make sure I've got everything I need ;-) .

Let us know if this does the job.

Cheers

Comment: Funny you say that, I was actually the one to answer the question you linked to! haha... I worked on this problem for like a week and finally figured it out after learning about quaternions, euler angles, spherical coordinates, and finally applying quaternions to my cameras view matrix. Hope it helps you!

Comment: Duh, I didn't notice, but thanks for the points ;-) . I know who to come to if I get any issues, thanks again.